# Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to group this case expression but unfortunately I'm getting an error.

```
select da.order_id, osl.itemid, sum(case when osl.sku = '00005' then 0 when osl.sku = '00006' then 0 else osl.price * sil.quantity end) merchcost, sum(sil.merchUnitCost * sil.quantity) cogs, sum(sil.quantity) quantity,
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM fcat.dbo.subscriptionskus a where a.itemId = osl.itemid) then 1
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM foam.dbo.subscriptionprogram b where b.orderStateLineId = osl.orderStateLine_id ) then 1
    else 0
    END as isAdmin,

    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM fcat.dbo.subscriptionskus a where a.itemId = osl.itemid) then CAST('subscriptionskus' as varchar(MAX))
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM foam.dbo.subscriptionprogram b where b.orderStateLineId = osl.orderStateLine_id ) then CAST('subscriptionprogram' as varchar(MAX))
    else 'NotListed'
    END as SubTable

from #dispatchAmounts da 
inner join orderstates os on os.order_id = da.order_id
inner join orderstatelines osl on osl.orderState_id = os.orderState_id
inner join shippingIntentLines sil on sil.orderStateLine_id = osl.orderStateLine_id and da.shippingIntent_nbr = sil.shippingIntent_nbr
where da.code = 'merch' and sil.quantity > 0
group by da.order_id, osl.itemid, CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM fcat.dbo.subscriptionskus a where a.itemId = osl.itemid) then 1
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM foam.dbo.subscriptionprogram b where b.orderStateLineId = osl.orderStateLine_id ) then 1
    else 0
    END,CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM fcat.dbo.subscriptionskus a where a.itemId = osl.itemid) then CAST('subscriptionskus' as varchar(MAX))
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM foam.dbo.subscriptionprogram b where b.orderStateLineId = osl.orderStateLine_id ) then CAST('subscriptionprogram' as varchar(MAX))
    else 'NotListed'
    END
```

ERROR:

> Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Is there anyway I can make this work?

Comment: Why are you using GROUP BY? You have no aggregates. Use DISTINCT if needed. But usually DISTINCT is a kludge to cover up a logical flaw in a query or the underlying tables. Given all those tables, the query seems to be logically incorrect in the first place since you will get many many rows from those joins and your select list contains 2 computed values but nothing else.

Comment: SMor is absolutely right. Maybe you can tell us what is the DDL+DML + your expected result... so we will understand if you need aggregate, but at this time seems like @SMor comment is the answer

Comment: @SMor sorry, wrong code. Added the missing codes.

Comment: @RonenAriely Sorry forgot to add the missing codes.

Comment: Please provide DDL+DML - queries to create the table(s) and to insert sample data, so it will be faster to execute and fix the query

Comment: Error message sum's your issue, you shouldn't use select statements (i.e. subquery)  on the Case statements that you are using it to Group by in this scenario, Provide a sample Table with sample data, so it would be easy to help you back with correct query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of suggestions. You are using `select *` in your case statements , but the columns referenced by '*' are not in your group by clause. To add them would be a bad way to fix the problem. Instead use ' `select 1` ' and see what happens.

Second recommendation is to just not use the `when exists` rather use `left join` using sub queries and use those in your `case` statements.

Comment: kinda followed your second recommendation. i just modified the subqueries and changed the condition on columns that is already available on the group by.

also removed the case statement on the group by.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did is.
1. Removed the Case Statement on the Group By.
2. Modified the SubQueries on the Case Statement. Followed @Shiv Sidhu recommendation.

Thanks for everyone.